# Using INNER JOIN to link mutliple columns from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and I have two tables, customers and table2.

Customers has the following columns: `Customer_Name`, `Address`, `City`, `State`
table2 has the following columns: `City`, `State`, `Zip_Code`

The tables were created to achieve 3rd normalization.  I don't have a problem using a single INSERT statement to load data to each table, but I'm unable to use INNER JOIN to combine the tables and run my query.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT Customer_Name, Address, City, State FROM customers 
INNER JOIN table2 ON customers.City=table2.City
INNER JOIN table2 ON customers.State=table2.State;
```

The error being returned is

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'table2'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use two different aliases for `table2`.

Comment: This really just looks like a matter of needing both conditions with `AND` in a single join's `ON` clause.   Remember, a joining `ON` clause (also `ORDER BY, GROUP BY`) is not necessarily an equality match 1:1 between columns. It can be any arbitrary expression which returns a true value.

Comment: I tried using "AND" between the two conditions, but it says #1052 - Column 'City' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Tony, I changed something in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
SELECT c.Customer_Name, c.Address, c.City, c.State FROM customers c
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON c.City=t2.City and c.State = t2.State
```

works?

Comment: It returns #1052 - Column 'City' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Well that worked.  I have to add zip_code to the query but that isn't a problem.  Why did you have to change to c.Customers, c.state, etc. though?

Comment: the `c` is used as an alias to reference the table `Customers`. Without the alias, SQL wouldn't know from which table to get the data.

Comment: Well zip_code is actually on table2. I do appreciate the help tonight. I couldn't find any references on the web for what I was trying to do, and none of the examples I saw mentioned anything about using an alias.

Comment: So, if you are getting it from table2 you must use the t2 alias.

Comment: I will. Thanks again for all of your help tonight!